# How to get the each array value in the switch case using typescript

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, knockout.js

I want get the value of each object in my switch case, based on the value i get in the case, I need to return some statements; Below is my code what I have tried:

```
// Here I will get the list of devices
    setFilterCollections() {
      return this.deviceService.getDeviceTypes();
    }

loadDevices(tenant: string) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.deviceTypes = this.setFilterCollections();
      Object.keys(this.deviceTypes).forEach((dType) => {
        console.log(this.deviceTypes[dType]);
// // Here also (In the above console) I am getting the list of devices [Please find attached list below of this question]. From switch case i am not getting the each device type. Am I doing something wrong?
        switch (this.deviceTypes[dType]) {
          case 'ComX':
            return this.ComXFilter = '{ "deviceType": "ComX" }';
          case 'IoTBridge':
            return this.ComXConnectedFilter = '{ "deviceType": "IoTBridge" }';
        }
       });
```

list includes from the console:
value
:
(10) ['ComX', 'IoTBridge', 'PAS400', 'PAS600', 'PAS800', 'LORADPAS', 'Lora', 'DPas', 'SE8000', 'Room Controller']
[[Prototype]]
:
Object

Please help me. I would really appreciate :) Thanks in advance!